# Running pdfcrack to include special characters in charset

Tags: grep, pipe, charset

I'm trying to recover a password from a PDF file using pdfcrack. I want to change the charset to include special characters.

Can I use some kind of i/o redirect to feed the contents of a a similiar file like this:

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*(''/\||""

into the charset parameter? Instead of trying to escape all the special characters properly into one huge command?

Answer (score 5):

**BASH ( Linux, Mac OS X, Windows with Cygwin )**

You don't have to escape anything, put the charset between `''` like this:

```
pdfcrack -c 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*(''/\||""' Some.pdf
```

But if you really want to read the charset from a file then you can do it like this:

```
MY_CHARS=$(cat charset.txt); pdfcrack -c $MY_CHARS Some.pdf
```

**CMD ( Windows only)**

Put the charset between `""` and only escape `"` itself with double `""` like this:

```
C:\>pdfcrack.exe -c "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%?^&*(''/\||'""" Some.pdf
```

Charset from file (same escaping rule need to be applied on the file content):

```
C:\>set /p CHARSET=<charset.txt & pdfcrack.exe -c %CHARSET% Some.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that I want to include the ' and " characters in the charset, how would that be done?

Comment: Edited my answer, I assumed you use BASH, because the question was tagged with grep.